# Error: 'myfile' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, file, input

Okay, so I'm trying to write encrypted text to a file.

For some reason, I am getting a not declared in this scope compile error.

Here's my encryption.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class encrypt{
    public:
        static void cryptText(std::string newpass)
        {
            int x = newpass.size();

            int output[x -1];

            for(int i = 0; i <= x -1; i++)
            {
                output[i] = (int)newpass[i];
                std::cout << char(output[i] + x);
                //Here I am trying to write output onto the file. For some reason, though,
                //I get the error.
                myfile.open ("passwords.thaddeus");
                myfile << output << std::endl;
                myfile.close();

            }

            std::cout << std::endl;

        }

};
```

I have looked at the cplusplus.com documentation for Input/Output with files. I copied their example program into Code::Blocks, and it worked perfectly. But when I try it, I get the error. It's strange because I included .

Comment: Could you reduce your code and information to the necessary minimum that still exhibits this specific error? Most of the information you provide isn’t relevant and just detracts from the problem. That said, the error is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Besides you have not declared `myfile` you got out of bounds array access at `output[i]+x` with i == 0

Comment: @Shafik Yaghmour I added that line, and instead get the same error but telling me ofstream was not declared in this scope.

Comment: @Syd Yes, that is b/c the sample also has `using namespace std;` which is bad so without that you need to do `std::ofstream myfile;`.

Answer (score 8):

You neither declared nor defined your `myfile` variable.

So, it doesn't exist in the current context and that's why you are getting this error.

You've missed this part of code `ofstream myfile;`

Comment: You are missing the need for `std::` since his code thankfully does not have `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Voted up! Yes, i've tested and you need set to `using namespace std;` into *.h global scope of header files. Don't forget add #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>, too.

Answer (score 5):

You miss the very basics of any language ... where is your `myfile` definition?

Comment: @Polentino myfile belongs to <fstream>. It's not a variable. It's practically the same exact code used in the example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ with a changed file name.

Comment: `ofstream myfile;` : taken straight from that example

Comment: @Syd No, it does not. And yes, it is a variable. And no, its not the same code.

Comment: @alternative Why then, here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/, does that program work?

Comment: @Syd because they define it. `ofstream myfile;`

Comment: @alternative Yeah, I thought so, so I added ofstream myfile. But then I get "ofstream" was not declared in this scope.

Comment: @Syd `using namespace std;`

Comment: @alternative There we go! Thank you. I didn't know ofstream belonged to iostream.

Comment: @Syd You won't have any functions at your disposal at all without includes, so they have to come from the C++ headers. And when you include a C++ header, you either need to use `std::...` or include the whole `std` namespace.

Comment: @alternative Oh, but I thought using :: is for specific headers. I thought iostream's :: was std::. So everything is std::? I'm confused. Because when I wrote my text adventure I had my own includes and I used Page::.

Comment: @Syd Everything in C++ standard library resides in std

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to use `ofstream`, so do `using namespace std;`

Then declare your `myfile` object: `ofstream myfile;`

General rule of thumb: Standard libraries never include a variable prefixed with 'my' for you to just use without declaring.